# Volume by revolution of quadrant of circle about its tangent

Tags: solid-of-revolution

An area bounded by a quadrant of a circle of radius $a$ and the tangents at its extremities revolves about one of the tangents. Find the volume so generated.

I am trying to use this formula:
$V=\pi\int_0^a [f(y)]^2dy$

I have used $f(y)=a-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}$

The answer I got is $\pi a^3(\frac{5}{3}-\frac{\pi}{2})$

But shouldn't the required volume be equal to that of a hemisphere that is $\frac{2}{3}\pi a^3$? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To my mind, the required volume occupies the same space as a hemisphere of radius $a$ would. So the answer should've been $\frac{2}{3}\pi a^3$, which is not what I got by integrating.

Comment: Just asking: Have you sketched the region of integration and the volume swept out under rotation? ;)

Comment: Yes I did. Is there something fundamental that I am missing? If you could just point me?

Comment: I've tried Pappus's Centroid Theorem and obtained $r^{3}\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{3}\Big)$

Comment: Could you put it up as an answer please?

Comment: @KirylPesotski: Times $2\pi$. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"An area bounded by a quadrant of a circle of radius a and the tangents at its extremities" is shaded. The solid swept out by revolving about one of the tangents is not a hemisphere:

[image: Revolving the outside of a quarter circle about an end tangent]

Comment: I feel embarrassed. I had a mental picture stuck to my head. Thank you!

Comment: So to get the required volume all I need to do is subtract the answer I got above,from $\pi a^3$, right?

Comment: I haven't checked the evaluation of your integral, but the set-up (your choice of $f(y) = a - \sqrt{a^{2} - y^{2}}$) is perfectly correct. Separately, we all get mental pictures stuck in mind; even when they're awry, dislodging them is difficult! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)